# 'str' object is not callable /django/contrib/auth/views.py in password_reset, line 185

Tags: python, django

I am trying to customize the PasswordResetForm form of `django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset`. I copied the code from [Django's website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/forms/) or the one [GitHub](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py), and put it in my forms.py. I changed the code from:

## forms.py

```
email = forms.EmailField(label=_("Email"), max_length=254)
```

to

```
email = forms.EmailField(label=_("Email"), max_length=254, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'E-mail'}))
```

and kept the remaining `PasswordResetForm` code intact.

## url.py

```
url(r'^password/reset/$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', {'post_reset_redirect': '/password/reset/done/', 'password_reset_form': 'forms.PasswordResetForm',}, name="password_reset"),
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/views.py in password_reset, line 185

185. form = password_reset_form()
```

I had it working without this customisation. I need the customisation because I want a `PlaceHolder` in the field. If I remove the key in the url it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value for `password_reset_form` should be the actual form class, not a string path to the form. For example, if you import the form with

```
from forms import PasswordResetForm
```

Then you would do:

```
url(r'^password/reset/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', {'post_reset_redirect': '/password/reset/done/', 'password_reset_form': PasswordResetForm}, name="password_reset"),
```

As an aside, using the string view like `django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset` is deprecated in Django 1.8, and will stop working in Django 1.10. Instead, you can import the auth views,

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
```

and change the url pattern to

```
url(r'^password/reset/$', auth_views.password_reset, {'post_reset_redirect': '/password/reset/done/', 'password_reset_form': PasswordResetForm}, name="password_reset"),
```

Comment: Great. Worked perfectly. Thanks for the answer and tip. There is a comma after .password_reset'. If you could change to help future searches. Also, is there a better way to customize and add the PlaceHolder or do I have to do what I did? (Add the whole form code)

Comment: I've removed the stray quote.

Comment: If you want to change the placeholder text, I think you need a custom form. It should be possible to import the built in form and subclass it, instead of copying all the code. You could then redefine the email field as you are doing, or change `self.fields['email'].widget` in the `__init__` method.

Comment: Nice. I will do that. Thanks!